# How to make large numbers of existing functions available in the scope of a class?

Tags: c++, class, function, scope, member

I need to make a large (100's of source files) project into a library, removing dozens of global variables by putting them all into a class object.

The problem is the thousand or so functions that now need to be members of this `class` so they have access to the object variables.

Otehr than adding `MyClass::` to every single function definition in the source files, is there a way to cheat and indicate that all the functions in a particular source file should be part of the `MyClass` scope?

Comment: Why?  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: A class with thousands of member functions sounds like a really bad idea.

Comment: Why?  Because that's what is being asked of me.  Making it all one big class seemed the best way to do what is required, to take a large single-threaded project and make it into a multi-threaded library. Time is limited too, so the less hand editing the better.

Answer (score 6):

Add all the globals to a `namespace`.

```
// MyGlobals.h
namespace MyGlobals
{
  extern int g_i;
  extern double g_d;
  extern A g_A;
}
```

Whatever files you want to access, do:

```
using namespace MyGlobals;
```

inside the header file. In this (`using namespace`) way you can indicate that all the variables should be accessible without using scope resolution `::` for that file. (i.e. you can simply access `g_i` instead of `MyGlobals::g_i` inside that file).

Also note that, you have to define all the global variables inside a `.cpp` file:

```
// MyGlobals.cpp
#include "MyGlobals.h"

int MyGlobals::g_i;
double MyGlobals::g_d;
A MyGlobals::g_A;
```

Comment: Definitely the obvious and simplest approach, but it would be inadequate *if* there is a requirement to allow multiple independent instances of the library functionality.  One mega-class is not a good way to do that either... :-].

Comment: You are right, I need it thread safe so have to remove all globals and statics.  How would you recommend I go about it?

Comment: @user750895, that would be a very subjective answer. You may have to change your design itself.